# Who is a "vocal customer"?

Tags: meaning

I know the meaning of vocal, but I don't know what does a vocal customer mean. Does it mean a gadfly customer?

Comment: You should state what you understand 'vocal' to mean. This is a figurative use that has become commonplace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a [vocal customer](http://knowledgebishop.com/2010/06/30/the-rise-of-the-vocal-customer/) means a louder, more  assertive customer. Thus a vocal customer does not necessary translate to a gadfly customer ( which means an annoying person, especially one who provokes others into action by criticism).